# jQuery datetimepicker disable specific time by date dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have a code here of my [datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) which will take away specific hours by date.

```
var specificDates = ['24/12/2014', '17/12/2014'];
var hoursToTakeAway = [[14, 15],[17]];
$('#from_date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
  timepicker: true,
  lang: 'en',
  onGenerate: function (ct, $i) {
    var ind = specificDates.indexOf(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'));
    $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').show();
    if (ind !== -1) {
      $('.xdsoft_time_variant .xdsoft_time').each(function (index) {
        if (hoursToTakeAway[ind].indexOf(parseInt($(this).text())) !== -1) {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My problem is how to manipulate it dynamically like this:

if I select in my datetimepicker:

```
07/05/2015 -take away hours: 1,2
13/05/2015 -take away hours: 3,4,5
```

How would I do that?

Comment: I have the same question here. Did you make any progress?